# "An almost any question" vs "Almost any question"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two sentences:

"Google can provide an answer to an almost any question." vs "Google can provide an answer to almost any question."

I understand that articles can sometimes be omitted for desired meaning like "It brought us little comfort" vs "It brought us a little comfort," but why should or shouldn't I use one in the examples above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article is not needed in your case. "An almost any question" sounds very strange and incorrect to me. You can think about article as an attributive or a modifier. In your case, you already have a modifier, which is **any**. So no article before "almost":

> Google can provide an answer to almost any question.

In case of "a little", it is a fixed expression which you cannot modify, so you cannot omit the article. It has a different meaning than the word "little". The meanings of the phrases "little comfort" and "a little comfort" are not the same.